# On active slide, append input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm throwing in the towel. I've been trying to figure this out all morning but can't for the life of me figure it out. I am still new to javascript, but I'm slowly getting there.

I'm trying to make my active slide div append a value to my search input.
I've been trying to do this through a simple hasClass if statement append val() to input.

The append is working, that is it will append the last if statement and in this case 'Rain Forest', however when the slide active state changes I can't get the value to change to the next appended value relative to the active slide. Does this make since?

If you could assist, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Here is the code I've been working with:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {  
/* dog shelter */
if($('.rsActiveSlide .rsABlock').hasClass("dog-shelter-input")){
        $(".feature-search #name_or_keywords").val('');
}else {
   $('.feature-search #name_or_keywords').val('Dog Shelter');
};

/* scolarships */
if($('.rsActiveSlide .rsABlock').hasClass("scholar-input")){
        $(".feature-search #name_or_keywords").val('');
}else {
   $('.feature-search #name_or_keywords').val('Scholarships');
};

/* Rain Forest */
if($('.rsActiveSlide .rsABlock').hasClass("forest-input")){
    $(".feature-search #name_or_keywords").val('');
}else {
     $('.feature-search #name_or_keywords').val('Rain Forest');
    };
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a fiddle  ? Then we can try to fix it. :)

Comment: Something tells me that if you're specifying `$('.feature-search #name_or_keywords')` instead of just `$('#name_or_keywords')` that you have multiple instances of `#name_or_keywords` on the same page. Is that the case? This could cause jQuery to behave unexpectedly.

Comment: The code is being executed on document.ready, that means for once when the page get loaded, if the 'slide active state' changes dynamically then you won't be able to produce the expected behavior. Solution: make function calls.

Comment: I unfortunately don't have a fiddle set up. But yeah, I didn't consider document.ready only allowing it to work once. I know that this might be stupid of me to ask, but what do mean by making function calls. In my ignorance, I thought that's what I was doing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coding it up here, for anyone who stumbles on the post later.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var slider = $(".royalSlider").data('royalSlider');
    slider.ev.on('rsAfterSlideChange', function(event) {
        //Your handler here
        //if($('.rsActiveSlide .rsABlock').hasClass("dog-shelter-input")){ ......
        //.......
        //...};
    });
)};
```

Comment: Rightly said. I know that this is right, it makes perfect since. As of now though, my code is getting stuck with defining the function
slider.ev.on('rsAfterSlideChange', function(event) {..} 
To to define it do I need to set set the variable of the slider? like so: var slider = $(".royalSlider").data('royalSlider');

Comment: exactly! I didn't notice that went undefined.. I'll update my code too.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you're using a slider plug-in or if you rolled your own. So at a high-level, you could do the following:

1) if it is a slider plug-in, does it allow you to supply a callback function when the slide changes (or when the animation is complete)? If so, provide a callback which encompasses your code to change the Search text.

2) if you rolled your own slider and likely are using `.animate()`, again, provide a callback function to `.animate()` that is called when the animation completes. Same callback as you would write in option #1.

I wrote my own light-weight slider and use the animation complete callback to take other actions. It should do the trick for you.

Hopefully points you in the right direction.

Comment: That was helpful. I am using royalslider. I'll check to see if they provide a callback function.

Comment: @BeDesigned I took a quick look at it, and it does have an event you can hook into. The slider has a slide change event for which you can provide a callback. See `slider.ev.on('rsAfterSlideChange', function(event) {
    // triggers after slide change
});
` For more, check out [RoyalSlider API Docs](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/royal-slider/documentation/#api)

Comment: So, something like `slider.ev.on('rsAfterSlideChange', function(event) { //Your complete if else logic });` should do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

@face, @emgee sorry resolving this issue earlier, I really thought it would work..
I'm still not figuring this out though. The code looks right..but I'm still getting errors.
Specifically with "slider.ev.on" -
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ev' of undefined

Here's my code.

```
       jQuery(document).ready(function($) { 

            var sliderEL = $('.new-royalslider-1'); 
            var slider = sliderEL.data('royalSlider');

            var addSearch = function() {

                if($('.rsActiveSlide .rsABlock').hasClass("dog-shelter-input")){
                    $(".feature-search #name_or_keywords").val('');
                 }else {
                   $('.feature-search #name_or_keywords').val('Dog Shelter');
                }

                 if($('.rsActiveSlide .rsABlock').hasClass("scholar-input")){
                    $(".feature-search .#name_or_keywords").val('');
                }else {
                   $('.feature-search #name_or_keywords').val('Scholarships');
                }
            };

            slider.ev.on('rsAfterSlideChange', addSearch);

            addSearch();

       });
```

some relevant topics were:

http://help.dimsemenov.com/discussions/royalslider-wordpress/1584-use-js-api-on-wordpress-version-to-change-image-scale-mode

http://help.dimsemenov.com/discussions/royalslider-wordpress/2601-adding-slider-index-to-wordpress-gives-a-js-error

I was going to write another question, because I am truly stumped,.. but it still apart of this main question