# Royalslider - Property 'ev' is undefined on 'slider.ev.on'

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

Per discussion: [On active slide, append input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17302892/on-active-slide-append-input/17304514?noredirect=1#comment25096851_17304514)

I'm still not figuring this out though, but I feel so close. I'm just stumped. The code looks right..but I'm still getting errors. Specifically with "slider.ev.on" - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ev' of undefined

Here's my code.

```
   jQuery(document).ready(function($) { 

        var sliderEL = $('.new-royalslider-1'); 
        var slider = sliderEL.data('royalSlider');

        var addSearch = function() {

            if($('.rsActiveSlide .rsABlock').hasClass("dog-shelter-input")){
                $(".feature-search #name_or_keywords").val('');
             }else {
               $('.feature-search #name_or_keywords').val('Dog Shelter');
            }

             if($('.rsActiveSlide .rsABlock').hasClass("scholar-input")){
                $(".feature-search .#name_or_keywords").val('');
            }else {
               $('.feature-search #name_or_keywords').val('Scholarships');
            }
        };

        slider.ev.on('rsAfterSlideChange', addSearch);

        addSearch();

   });
```

some relevant topics were:

http://help.dimsemenov.com/discussions/royalslider-wordpress/1584-use-js-api-on-wordpress-version-to-change-image-scale-mode

http://help.dimsemenov.com/discussions/royalslider-wordpress/2601-adding-slider-index-to-wordpress-gives-a-js-error

Answer (score 0):

Based on your post it sounds like two different issues...

`Property 'ev' is undefined on 'slider.ev.on'`: This makes it sound as if slider is defined but ev is not (I was having this issue yesterday, which is how I came across this question).

If this is the case then perhaps try changing `new-royalslider-1` to `royalSlider` everywhere.

--

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ev' of undefined`: This makes it sound as if slider itself is not defined.

If this is the case, and the code above is all that you have, then I'd say you're missing actually initializing the slider:

```
$('.royalSlider').royalSlider({ /* options */ });
var slider = $('.royalSlider').data('royalSlider');
slider.ev.on('rsAfterSlideChange', addSearch);
```

Comment: Thanks! `mySlider.data('royalSlider');` is indeed required before call events api